# How can I create custom templates folders in C#?

Tags: c#, templates, mediatr

In theses days I trying to use onion architecture with dotnet core and mediatr library. it's very tedious for me writing code for each use case. I have 8 entities and writing a crud for each entity. I have to create 32 use cases. For this reason, i want to create a command that it write the 4 use case in the crud per each entity.

Similar to this

```
Dotnet create crud user
```

And the response command will be like theses

```
User
|-create
..| cretaeUserRequest.cs
..| cretaeUserHandler.cs
..| cretaeUserResponse.cs
..| cretaeUserRequestValidator.cs
|-read
..| ReadUserRequest.cs
..| ReadUserHandler.cs
..| ReadUserResponse.cs
|-update
..| UpdateUserRequest.cs
..| UpdateUserHandler.cs
..| UpdateUserResponse.cs
..| UpdateeUserRequestValidator.cs
|-delete
..| deleteUserRequest.cs
..| deleteUserHandler.cs
..| deleteUserResponse.cs
..| deleteUserRequestValidator.cs
```

Each file have a template.

Answer (score 0):

Official Microsoft guideline, if you follow Create a project template for dotnet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-project-template

After that look at the create a template package.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-template-package

Both links has also a GitHub sample:

https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-item-template

That will help you achieve your goal.